# I need to rename a TFS folder-full of files, to remove a specific block of text

Tags: powershell, tfs, powershell-cmdlet

I'm using VS 2015, so the TFSCMDLets add-in for 2015.  TFS server is 2013.

The old "New-TfsPendingChange -Rename" syntax that I found here on SO is no longer supported, both per the docs and per the error messages I get when I try.

I can't just check them out and rename them using the filesystem rename command, because that causes TFS to lose track of the file.

I've also tried this using tf.exe, where the commands I need are available, but it can't seem to figure out the workspace to use, even though the containing folder only maps to a single workspace.  In this case it works fine when passed a literal filename, but fails when passing a path using foreach, like this:
tf workspaces /collection:devtfs\DeltaWA_ITA_BI

dir "C:\TFS\BusinessIntelligence\Database\Reporting_Prod\Test Views\" -filter "*.View.sql" | foreach { $newname = $*.Name -replace ".View.sql", ".sql"; tf rename $* $newname }

Does anyone have a sample script that works in VS2015, TFS 2013?

Comment: SO cannot give recommendations or sources for code. SO is here to help with code you wrote. You need to review the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: What's detail error message did you get for the workspace error?

Answer (score 0):

You should **avoid** renaming items managed by TFVC using your operating system (for example, using Windows File Explorer, or the rename command in the Windows command prompt). Instead, do this in **Source Control Explorer**:

1. In Source Control Explorer, select the file that you want to edit,
   open its shortcut menu, and choose **Rename**.
2. Type the desired name for the item.

If you want to use command  prompt or script to do this, you could use [`tf rename`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/rename-command-team-foundation-version-control) command. Not sure the detail error message for your workspace error.

However, you need to make sure that you are running the commands from a **mapped folder**, you can run [tf workfold](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/workfold-command) to double check if the current folder is mapped or not.

If it's mapped and the error still exists, you might have a problem with your workspace cache.  Try to **remove cache** through tf workspaces command:

```
tf workspaces /remove:(*|workspace1[,workspace2,...]) 
/collection:(*|TeamProjectCollectionUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

The overall answer turned out be in two parts:
1. You really must execute tf.exe in the folder where you want the work done.  I saw this in the code I looked at, but didn't understand it was a requirement.
2. This means you have to get tf.exe into your path.  Got help from a coworker on that.

After that, my tiny script worked as desired.

I still don't see a way to do this with TFS CMDLets.  This is kind of a pity, bu not really important.

Thanks for the assistance!